Google Chat dialog window inputText validation in Java
In documentation mentioned that Action has the requiredWidgets that can be used for some validation. I can't find the same possibility for Java GoogleAppsCardV1Action.
Does someone know about other possibility to configure input field with some validation on Google Chat side?
I expect to create a text input with validation that will make the fields required and only allow numbers for Java code.
